# cangen vcan0 command returns write: Network is Down

Tags: linux, can-bus, socketcan

Fairly new to this, any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. 
Trying to run a virtual CAN network using can-utils, but I keep getting Network down message when I try to do a candump or cangen.

Here is some of the general process...

$: lsmod shows I have these....

```
Module                  Size  Used by
can_raw                20480  0
slcan                  16384  0
vcan                   16384  0
can                    45056  1 can_raw
```

Followed by these commands:

$ sudo ip link add name vcan0 type vcan

$ ifconfig vcan

```
vcan0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-
00-00-00-00  
      NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

$ cangen vcan0

gives me

```
write:Network is down.
```

Does this have something to do with setting chmod?

Answer (score 2):

Better with `ip`:

```
ip link set vcan0 up
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I needed to enter this

```
sudo ifconfig vcan0 up
```

I was entering that, minus the 'up'.